How many dots are there?
Given a string of printable ASCII, count the dots.
The following characters have one dot each: i j . ; ! ?. This character has two dots: :. No other characters have dots.
Rules

Default I/O rules and standard rules apply. Standard loopholes are forbidden.

This is code-golf; shortest solution in bytes wins.


Test cases
Input                                   Output
Sphinx of black quartz, judge my vow!      3
Lorem ipsum: dolor sit amet?               5
Programming Puzzles & Code Golf            1
ij.;!?:                                    8
pericardiomediastinitis                    6
formaldehydesulphoxylate                   0
<empty string>                             0

This question has 58 dots.

Sandbox

Can we take input as an array of characters?

@Shaggy Yes.

Racket, 60 bytes
(λ(s'(curryr regexp-match* s)`length)(+`'"[ij.;!?:]"`'":"))

Takes a string and runs a regexp twice, nothing fancy, but I'm pleased with the garble of symbols. Heavily relies on default arguments, which write and some formatting elucidates:
(λ (s [quote (curryr regexp-match* s)] [quasiquote length])
  (+ (quasiquote (quote "[ij.;!?:]")) (quasiquote (quote ":"))))

Try it online!

Uiua, 18 15 bytes
/+♭⊞="ij.::;!?"

Try it: Uiua pad
Explanation: Sum of the flattened equality table of the input with "ij.::;!?".

/+♭ is equivalent to ⧻⊚ for booleans, as demonstrated in
my answer.

@janMakoso Clever, upvoted.

Google Sheets, 45 bytes
=len(regexreplace(A1,"(:)|[^ij.;!?]","$1$1"))

Put the text string in cell A1 and the formula in cell B1.

(-1 thanks to emanresu A)

.split\:`.join`::`saves a few bytes on the latter (edit: actually, replacing'::'with10` is better)

@emanresuA thanks, but using a better regex saves many more.

Python 3, 42 37 bytes
lambda a:sum(map(a.count,'ij.;!?::'))

Try it online!

You can save some bytes with map

JavaScript (Node.js), 50 bytes
x=>[...'ij.;!?::'].flatMap(c=>x.split(c)).length-8

Try it online!

Perl 5 -p0, 20 bytes
$_=y/ij.;!?://+y/://

Try it online!

This doesn't seem to work for inputs with newlines (per TIO at least). Do we care?

@GregMartin It does if you add a -0 on the command line.  There's no change needed to the code itself to support it.

@GregMartin By consensus, printable ASCII doesn’t include newlines.

Zsh, 28 bytes
<<<${#${1//:/..}//[^ij;.!?]}

Try it online!
Replace : with .., then remove all non-dot characters and print the string length

Vyxal, 14 bytes
`ij.::;!?`fvO∑

Try it Online!
            O  # Count in input
          fv   # Each of
`ij.::;!?`     # String "ij.::;!?"
             ∑ # sum counts


R, 43 bytes
\(s)nchar(gsub("(:)|[^ij.;!?]","\\1\\1",s))

Attempt This Online!
Port of @doubleunary's Google Sheets answer.

R, 48 44 bytes
Edit: -4 bytes porting @Luis Mendo's MATL answer.
\(s)sum(outer(utf8ToInt("ij.;!?::"),s,`==`))

Attempt This Online!
Takes input as a vector of character codes.

JavaScript (V8), 44 bytes
t=>t.replace(/(:)|[^ij.;!?]/g,'$1$1').length

Try it online!
Port of my Google Sheets answer.
(-1 thanks to emanresu A)

44

Arturo, 41 bytes
$=>[replace&":"{..}|match"[ij.;!?]"|size]

Try it!

Uiua, 14 bytes
⧻⊚⊞="ij.;!?::"

Try it online!
Explanation

⊞=: The outer product of equality between the literal "ij.;!?::", and the  input
⧻⊚: count where elements equal one (true)


K (ngn/k), 19 bytes
+//"ij.;!?::"=\:

Try it online!

Jelly,  14  13 bytes
ċⱮ“::ij.;!?”S

A monadic Link that accepts a list of characters and yields the number of dots.
Try it online!
How?
ċⱮ“::ij.;!?”S - Link: list of characters, T
  “::ij.;!?”  - list of characters -> "::ij.;!?"
 Ɱ            - map with:
ċ             -   {T} count {char}
            S - sum


Japt -mx, 17 16 15 14 bytes
This could be 12 bytes in v2 but there seems to be a bug with S.è(x) that only counts a maximum of 1 occurrence of x.
Takes input as an array of characters.
"!.::;?ij"oU Ê

Try it
"..."oU Ê     :Implicit map of each U in the input array
"..."         :The necessary characters, with : duplicated
     oU       :Keep only those characters that appear in U
        Ê     :Length
              :Implicit output of sum of resulting array


iogii, 13 bytes
rq__"ij.;!?::

run it here!!
Repeat the input so that the following eQual check is essentially a cartesian product instead of element by element, then sum and sum again.
The string of dot characters is placed at the end so it can be unterminated, it becomes the left arg to equal using iogii's rotation trick.

Vyxal 3.3.0 d, 11 bytes
ᵒ="ij.::;!?

Try it Online!
I downgraded to Vyxal 3.3.0 because that's the most recent version which still supports Nilad moving, a feature which was removed because it makes debugging super annoying but makes this program a byte shorter because it lets me move the string to the end of the line instead of having it at the front, saving a byte on the closing quotation mark.
The logic is super simple: Take the outer product of equality with the string ij.::;!?, and d deeply sums the result.

Who removed their upvote when I made my solution shorter lol

APL+WIN, 29 bytes
Prompts for string:
(+/s∊'ij.;!?.')+2×+/(s←⎕)∊':'

Try it online! Thanks to Dyalog Classic

MATL, 15 bytes
0h'ij.;!?::'!=z

Try it online! Or verify all test cases.
How it works
0h         % Implicit input. Attach character 0. This is needed to avoid empty string
'ij.;!?::' % Push this string. Note that ':' appears twice
!          % Transpose into a column vector
=          % Matrix of all pair-wise comparisons
z          % Number of non-zeros. Implicit display


05AB1E, 13 bytes
"!.::;?ij"S¢O

Try it online or verify all test cases.
Explanation:
"!.::;?ij"    # Push this string (note the "::")
          S   # Convert it to a list of characters
           ¢  # Count each of those characters in the (implicit) input-string
            O # Sum the counts together
              # (after which the result is output implicitly)

Unfortunately, the shortest compressed version of this character-list I could find is 1 byte longer: •м€2Q¸Ü•žQÅв¢O. Also, there are some minor variations possible for the same byte-count: ":!.;?ij"Ć€¢O or "!.;?ij:"¤ª¢O.

JavaScript (ES6), 49 bytes
Expects an array of characters.
a=>a.map(c=>t+=c==":"?2:/[ij.;!?]/.test(c),t=0)|t

Try it online!

Pyth, 12 bytes
sm/"ij.::;!?

Try it online!

J, 19 bytes
1#.1#.'ij.::;!?'=/]

Works the same as most.
Attempt This Online!
1#.1#.'ij.::;!?'=/]
                  ]   NB. input string
      'ij.::;!?'      NB. string literal
                =/    NB. equality table
   1#.                NB. sum rows
1#.                   NB. sum resulting list


Haskell, 34 bytes
f x=sum[1|c<-x,v<-"ij.;!?::",c==v]

Try it online!

Retina 0.8.2, 14 13 bytes
:
..
[!.;?ij]

Try it online! Link includes test cases. Explanation: :s are "rotated", then the relevant characters are counted which produces the desired result. Edit: Saved 1 byte thanks to @m90.

If : is replaced with .. instead, then : can be omitted from the last line.

Javascript - 290 242 240 bytes
Counting the dots on a canvas.
s=>[...s].map(a=>{for(x=document.createElement`canvas`.getContext`2d`,x.font="40Q A",x.fillText(a,10,50),d=x.getImageData(i=0,0,99,99).data;++i<1e4;)t+=d[j=i*4+3]>9&&g(j,p=0)<25},t=0,g=i=>d[i]?g(i+4,p++,d[i]=0,g(i-4),g(i+396),g(i-396)):p)|t


-45 -46 bytes thanks to @Shaggy!

JSFiddle

You're always allowed to do an intentionally suboptimal approach and still golf that approach.

Some very quick savings to get you down to 245, but there's a lot more room for improvement.

Forgot to include this above: 40px can be 40Q

@Shaggy, nice! First time I have seen the quarter-millimeters (Q) unit.

Doesn't work fine here, get 0 on ij.

@l4m2 I get 2 with ij but I think it depends on the fonts installed in your OS. See what happens if you mess around with the <25

<30 works fine

@l4m2 cool. What did you test with?

Firefox 130.0.1, Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Red, 69 bytes
func[s][n: 0 foreach c s[n: n + case[find"ij.;!?"c 1 c =#":"2 1 0]]n]

Try it online!

Bash+coreutils, 33 bytes
tr -cd ij.\;!?<<<${1//:/..}|wc -c

Attempt This Online!
Is also optimal for zsh, I think.
explanation:
                 ${1//:/..} #replace all : with .. in first argument
              <<<           #and pass it to standard input of...
tr -cd ij.\;!?              # from stdin, output only characters specified to stdout
                           |wc -c # pass stdout to stdin of: count chars in stdin
#implicit output stdout to terminal


Charcoal, 14 bytes
ＩΣＥ!.::;?ij№θι

Try it online! Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:
   !.::;?ij     Literal string `!.::;?ij`
  Ｅ             Map over characters
           №    Count of
             ι  Current character
            θ   In input string
 Σ              Take the sum
Ｉ               Cast to string
                Implicitly print


C# (.NET Core), 50 bytes
s=>Regex.Replace(s,"(:)|[^!?;:.ij]","$1$1").Length

Try it online!
I tried to find a shorter/more interesting solution but the regex approach works really well.

Google Sheets, 56 bytes
=LEN(REGEXREPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,":","ii"),"[^ij.;!?]",))


APL(Dyalog Unicode), 17 bytes SBCS
A 2 train that counts set bits in the equality table between input and string ::ij.;!?.
≢∘⍸∘.=∘'::ij.;!?'

Try it on APLgolf!

Dart, 120 bytes
main(List<String>y,{i=0,j=0,x}){x=y[0];for(;i<x.length;i++){if('ij.;!?'.contains(x[i]))j++;if(x[i]==':')j+=2;}print(j);}

Try it online!
Only takes one string at a time.

85 bytes

C (gcc), 64 56 55 bytes

-8 bytes thanks to @AZTECCO!

-1 byte thanks to @ceilingcat!


f(int*a){a=*a?(*a-58?!!index("ij.;!?",*a):2)+f(++a):0;}

Try it online!

56 bytes

@AZTECCO, very nice!

Haskell + hgl, 16 bytes
mF$fce"ij.;?!::"

Attempt This Online!
Explanation
Counts the number of times each character in the string occurs in the string ij.;?!:: and sums them.
Reflection
Very simple answer, so can't expect much in the way of improvements to hgl. However I do think it could potentially be useful to have mF<fce (equivalently cnT<eqo) as a built in function. This essentially counts the number of equal pairs between two lists, and is extremely similar to how ca already works.

PHP, 98 74 73 bytes
$f=fn($i)=>preg_replace(['/:/','/[ij.;!?]/'],['.'],$i,-1,$c)!==null?$c:0;

Try it online!
PHP, 87 bytes
$f=fn($i)=>str_replace(str_split('ij.;!?'),'',str_replace(':','..',$i),$c)!==null?$c:0;

Try it online!
Replacing : with .. inspired from @GammaFunction.
Note: in case of null return from replacement, maybe we should use 'N/A' instead of 0 for preg_replace;

Those byte counts are missing the $r=str_split('ij.;!?') bit?

At first glance I though I can get rid of those bytes. Thank you!

# Kotlin, 57 bytes
val f={s:String->"ij.;!?::".map{c->s.count{it==c}}.sum()}

Try it online!
Or if you don't count bytes for lambda declarations:
Kotlin 1.3 or older, 44 bytes
{s->"ij.;!?::".map{c->s.count{it==c}}.sum()}

Try it online!
Where val f:(String)->Int= is the header.
Kotlin 1.4+, 40 bytes
{s->"ij.;!?::".sumOf{c->s.count{it==c}}}

Online Test
Again, val f:(String)->Int= as the header.
sumOf was introduced in Kotlin 1.4+

Hello. Welcome to the site. I don't think you need to count the val f= bit. If you can use the lambda expression inline then you only have to count those bytes. (It's been a bit since I've written any Kotlin). Also if you have code that works on a particular platform you can specify "Kotlin + IntelliJ" or what-have-you as the language. Platform specific tricks can be pretty cool.

@WheatWizard Okay thanks, I fixed it a bit, I also identified the issue now, it's not specifically IntelliJ that makes it work, it's because sumOf was introduced in Kotlin 1.4, and I assume online compilers use an older version, I've also formatted my functions (and counted bytes) based on this

AWK, 59 48 37 bytes
$0=gsub(/[ij\.;!\?]/,x)+2*gsub(/:/,x)

$0=                     # set output to
gsub(/[ij\.;!\?]/,x)    # get count of subs
+2*gsub(/:/,x)          # 2 for colon

Try it online!
awk -F '' '{for(;++i<=NF;x+=$i~/:/)x+=$i~/[ij\.;!\?:]/}$0=x'

BEGIN{FS=X}{for(;++i<=NF;x+=$i~/:/)x+=$i~/[ij\.;!\?:]/}$0=x

awk -F ''             # split characters
{for(;++i<=NF;        # for each character
x+=$i~/:/)            # add one for the colon
x+=$i~/[ij\.;!\?:]/}  # add one if it matches 
$0=x                  # print

